# Trying to Understand Gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I'm trying to wrap my head around the geometric meaning of gradient in three dimensions.

If I have vector $\vec r=x(t) \hat i+y(t) \hat j+z(t) \hat k$ and a surface $U(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ which is not equal to a constant i.e. $U(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \ne c$.

And now if I still find total differential:

$$dU=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}++\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}\ne 0$$
$$\implies dU=<\frac{\partial U}{\partial x},\frac{\partial U}{\partial y},\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}><\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}>=\nabla U \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}\ne 0$$

$\implies \nabla U$ and $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$ are not orthogonal to each other.

The whole idea of the gradient presented in books and materials is associated to $U(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = c$.

My question is how is the gradient to be interpreted when $U(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \ne c$ in which case it seems the $\nabla U$ and the tangential vector $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$ are not perpendicular to each other?Or is it not possible to define gradient in this case.

Comment: The phrase “a surface $U(x,y,z)$” makes no sense. $U$ is a function, not a surface. But the set of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $U(x,y,z)$ equals some constant $c$ is (typically) a surface.

Comment: $f(x,y,z)=t^2$ is this not a surface?

Comment: Unless you explain a bit more what that is even supposed to *mean*, it's impossible to answer that question.

Comment: is f(x,y,z)=g(t) not a surface? where g(t) is some function of t....

Comment: That didn't make things any clearer. Is $f$ a given function? What is $t$?